# Welcome Page - ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I am working on a website, in ASP.NET MVC 4, where a user is redirected to a welcome page when they first get to the website, sort of like Forbes. It currently uses cookies, and when they go to any page on the site it checks to see if they have a cookie called "Visited". If they do it allows them into the site, but if not it redirects them to the welcome page, where they get the cookie and a link allows them to continue to the site they were hoping for.

Would this be the most efficient method of creating a welcome page, or is there a cleaner or safer method I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the user must not be authenticated right? In that case, you can manage if this user already visited your site, by using `localStorage`, the information will stays in the browser, this way, you must not be sending and receiving cookies.

Comment: So, what exactly is 'localStorage' and how can I use it?

Comment: localStorage is a browser's storage that persists data, even when the browser is closed and reopened. Here is an example, how to write data and how to read data: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Oh, sorry. I should have been more specific. I want them to see the message every time they close the browser and reopen it, just to keep their knowledge of the website's features up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got it to work with cookies. I ended up creating an Attribute that checks to see if the Request has a cookie called "Visited". If it does, they are let through to whatever page they were attempting to get to. Otherwise, it redirects them to "/Welcome/Index", where the Controller gives them the cookie, and shows them a page that has information about the website.

---

I found how to create attributes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056(v=vs.100).aspx) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056(v=vs.100).aspx).

---

This is my Visited Attribute class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace LapisRealmv2.Controllers
{
    public class Visited : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("Visited"))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Welcome/Index");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

This is my Welcome Controller (for help with creating cookies):

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace LapisRealmv2.Controllers
{
    public class WelcomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Visited");
            // The cookie will expire when the browser is closed.
            this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```